# Does $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{p(x)+q(x)}$ exist if $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\frac{f(x)}{p(x)}+\frac{g(x)}{q(x)}\right]$ exists?

Tags: limits

Let $f(x)/p(x)$ and $g(x)/q(x)$ be rational functions in their simplest forms, with $\text{deg}(f)\neq\text{deg}(g)$ and $\text{deg}(p)\neq\text{deg}(q)$. Then $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\frac{f(x)}{p(x)}+\frac{g(x)}{q(x)}\right] \,\text{exists}\implies
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{p(x)+q(x)}\,\text{exists}\,\,\,?$$

---

A seemingly true counterexample would be $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\frac{x}{x^2}+\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right] =0\implies
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x+1}{1}=\infty$$ but $x/x^2=1/x$ is not in its simplest form and the denominators have the same degree.

We could also write $$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{p(x)+q(x)}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\frac{f(x)}{p(x)+q(x)}+\frac{g(x)}{p(x)+q(x)}\right]\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\frac{f/p}{1+q/p}+\frac{g/q}{1+p/q}\right]\end{align}$$ and this would prove the statement if $\lim_{x\to\infty} q/p\neq0,-1$ exists.

Comment: How about the following tweak of your example? $$\frac{x}{1+x^2}+\frac{x}{1-x^2}$$

Comment: @SangchulLee Yes that would work, thanks! As an extension, do you have an example like this where $\text{deg}(f)\neq\text{deg}(p)$ and $\text{deg}(g)\neq\text{deg}(q)$?  This is so that the numerators/denominators don't 'cancel out' after summing.

Comment: @SangchulLee I have thus edited the question as nobody has provided an answer as of now.

Comment: Do you mean $\deg(f)\neq\deg(g)$ and likewise for denominators?

Comment: How about $$\frac{1+x^3}{x}+\frac{1-x^4}{x^2}$$

Comment: @SangchulLee Clever trick! If you post this as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example would be $\,\frac{x^2}{x-1} + \frac{-x}{1}\,$ which goes to $\,1\,$ but $\,\frac{x^2 - x}{x - 1 + 1} = x-1\,$  goes to $\,\infty\,$ as $\,x\to\infty.$

However, this example depends on one numerator having negative leading sign. In we restrict to polynomials with **positive** leading coefficient, then
 $\, f/p+g/q \to L < \infty \,$ 
**does** imply that
 $\,(f+g)/(p+q)  \to M < \infty.\,$
As abbreviation, let $\,dp := \text{deg}(p)\,$ for any polynomial $\,p\,.$
Since
$\, f/p+g/q \to L < \infty \,$ and **both** $\,f/q\,$ and $\,g/q\,$ must converge, this means
  $\,df \leq dp \,$ and $\,dg \leq dq.\,$
 We are given $\,dp \neq dq\,$ so assume WLOG that 
 $\,dp >dq.\,$
 Now we are given
 $\,df \neq dg\,$ so there are two cases.

Case $1$: $\,df < dg.\,$
 In $\,(f\!+\!g)/(p\!+\!q),\,$
we have $\,d(f\!+\!q) = dg \leq dq < dp = d(p\!+\!q).\,$
 Now$\,(f\!+\!g)/(p\!+\!q) \! \to \!0 .\,$

Case $2$: $\, df > dg.\,$ We have $\,d(f\!+\!q) = df \leq dp = d(p\!+\!q).\,$
Now$\,(f\!+\!g)/(p\!+\!q) \! \to \!M <\infty .\,$